# WPF app not updating timeout binding info for WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a solution that contains a WCF service, a Windows Service (to host it), and a WPF application to consume it. I have a "data access dll" that I am referencing the service from. When I search the solution for a service it finds it and references it without any issues and it also generates the app.config file for it.

The problem I am having is, the binding info is not all updating. My service has timeouts configured which are not being generated/updated in the local app.config file. I was able to get around it by just manually adding them in and it works fine; however, I would like to be able to update them automatically.

This is the configuration for the service binding:

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamingBinding" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
          transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

This is what is being generated when I reference the service (notice it is missing the timeout(s)):

```
<bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ITestService" transferMode="Streamed">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong/missing??

Thank you in advance!

---

Per request below is my app.config for the service and the app.config for the client:

Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamingBinding" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
          transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TestService.Wcf.TestServiceWcf">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamingBinding"
          contract="TestService.Wcf.ITestServiceWcf">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8525/TestServiceService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ITestServiceWcf" transferMode="Streamed">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8525/TestServiceService"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ITestServiceWcf"
                contract="TestServiceService.ITestServiceWcf" name="NetTcpBinding_ITestServiceWcf">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you associated "StreamingBinding" with your endpoint? It might be worth posting everything between "System.serviceModel" tags to see what is missing.
From your post it appears that though you are using netTcpBinding at both ends but they may not be from same endpoint, i.e. client might be using just default settings.

```
<services>
      <service name="ServiceName">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamingBinding"
          name="NetTcpEndPoint" contract="ServiceContractName" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: I updated the info above to show the full app.config files. The one for the client is auto generated when I referenced the service in the same solution